# How to add and remove characters from an URL using radio buttons? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, url, radio-button

I have three radio buttons that are suppose to append text to an URL. That part is working, but I need I need the appended text to be one at a time, so it will look like one of these:

```
image-instagram.jpg
image-twitter.jpg
image-mobile.jpg
```

Not like it currently does:

```
image-instagram.jpgtwitter.jpgmobile.jpg
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/jangeltun/pen/yLYJeGG)

```js
function addInstagramLink(){
    var link = document.getElementById('url');
    link.href += "-instagram.jpg";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link;
}

function addTwitterLink(){
    var link = document.getElementById('url');
    link.href += "-twitter.jpg";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link;
}

function addMobileLink(){
    var link = document.getElementById('url');
    link.href += "-mobile.jpg";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a id="url" href="image" target="_blank">image link</a>
</div>
<div>
    Instagram <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:addInstagramLink();" name="graphicSize" id="instaSize" value="Instagram" checked>
    Twitter <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:addTwitterLink();" name="graphicSize" id="twitterSize" value="Twitter">
    Mobile <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:addMobileLink();" name="graphicSize" id="mobileSize" value="Mobile">
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single function with parameter passing. Less code will be required in this case.

```
<div>
    <a id="url" href="image" target="_blank">image link</a>
</div>
<div>
    Instagram <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:addLink('image-instagram.jpg');" name="graphicSize" id="instaSize" value="Instagram" checked> Twitter <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:addLink('image-twitter.jpg');" name="graphicSize" id="twitterSize"
        value="Twitter"> Mobile
    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:addLink('image-mobile.jpg');" name="graphicSize" id="mobileSize" value="Mobile">
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Function

```
function addLink(linkValue) {
        var link = document.getElementById('url');
        link.href = linkValue;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link.href;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed the first part of the link to be dynamic and not replace the entire link, but I was able to do that by using two url's. Probably not the best solution, but it works. Updated the Codepen: https://codepen.io/jangeltun/pen/yLYJeGG

Answer (score 0):

What about the next code:

```
function addInstagramLink(){
  var link = document.getElementById('url');
  link.href = 'image-instagram.jpg';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link.href;
}

function addTwitterLink(){
  var link = document.getElementById('url');
  link.href = 'image-twitter.jpg';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  link.href;
}

function addMobileLink(){
  var link = document.getElementById('url');
  link.href= 'image-mobile.jpg';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = link.href;
}
```